# Magento javascript undefined is not a function jquery selectric?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, jquery-plugins, undefined

I am having a problem on my site trying to add a few dropdown menus to the header!

I am using Magento CE 1.8.0 with Airhotels module.

The weird thing is on some pages it works and on some it doesn't. It seems to me that pages related directly to Airhotels module don't seem to be working, maybe this is a clue?

As you can see from these images I am getting error `undefined is not a function`:

[image]

- broken

[image]

- working

I have added this line to airhotels.xml under All Pages

`<action method="addJs"><script>airhotels/jquery.selectric.js</script></action>`

This is my jQuery script located in `public_html\app\design\frontend\default\stylish\template\page\html\header.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jQnc = jQuery.noConflict();

jQnc(document).ready(function(){

  jQnc('#header-profile-links').selectric();
  jQnc('#header-browse-links').selectric();
  jQnc('#custom-currency-selector').selectric(); 

  jQnc('#customOptions').selectric({
    onChange: function(element){
    if(jQnc(element).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("english") >= 0) {
        jQnc('p#labelFi').css('background','url(http://sleepmyhome.com/skin/frontend/default/stylish/images/flag_en.png) 10% 50% no-repeat');
        jQnc('p#labelFi').removeClass('labelFi').addClass('labelEn');
        window.location.href = jQnc(element).val();
        }
    if(jQnc(element).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("finnish") >= 0) {
        jQnc('p#labelEn').css('background','url(http://sleepmyhome.com/skin/frontend/default/stylish/images/flag_fi.png) 10% 50% no-repeat');
        jQnc('p#labelEn').removeClass('labelEn').addClass('labelFi');
        window.location.href = jQnc(element).val();
        }
    },
    optionsItemBuilder: function(itemData, element, index){
    jQnc('#customOptions').addClass("customOptions langSelectWidth");
        return element.val().length ? '<span class="ico ico-' + element.attr('title') +  '"></span>' + itemData.text : itemData.text;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated I am really stuck!

Comment: use $.noConflict(); to jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: If I try this it ends up not working at all. Tried in both header.phtml and jquery.selectric.js.

Comment: ok do one thing ... add jquery library again just above the jquery.selectric.js and then check .... and use the same code which you mentioned above

Comment: Hi, I tried that but that didn't work either. Today I THINK I have found the problem. I removed all the "common.js" includes from airhotels.xml (I commented them out http://puu.sh/aGVwS.png). Now the script seems to be working fine on every page. 

Now my problem would be how can I use "common.js" and selectric at the same time. I looked at the "common.js" file and

 this is how it begins http://puu.sh/aGVAF.png 

and this is how it ends http://puu.sh/aGVBi.png . Could there be something here?

If you need more information to help me please inform!

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with getting the value
try something like that (this is bad example - next one is good):

```
<ul class="customOptions">
    <li class="">Select something</li>
    <li class=""><span> Choice 1</span></li>
    <li class="selected"><span> Choice 2</span></li>
    <li class=""><span> Choice 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

with JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.customOptions').selectric({
        maxHeight: 300,
        onChange: function(element) {
           alert( $(element).val() );
        }
    });
});
```

result is empty,

but now try something like this:

```
<ul class="customOptions">
    <li class="">Select something</li>
    <li class=""><span data-value="value1"> Choice 1</span></li>
    <li class="selected"><span data-value="value2"> Choice 2</span></li>
    <li class=""><span data-value="value2"> Choice 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

put something into LI - ie.  Choice 1 with data attribute where you put some custom values:

```
$(function(){
    $('.customOptions').selectric({
        maxHeight: 300,
        onChange: function(element) {
           alert( $('.selectricItems').find('.selected span').attr('data-value') );
        }
    });
});
```

i think that if you use this method you should be able to get selected value from data-attr  and do whatever you want. (REMEMBER - do not put data-attr=""  into LI tag - it will not work)